# Manga where the main character kills a demon as human when he was controlling other women as his puppets

Tags: story-identification, comics, manga, webcomics

So this all is playing in modern era.

The MC is an ordinary high school student with several part-time jobs. I remember that from the first chapters. He was just working in a superstore at night, where a demon disguised as a human was buying condoms for each night with a different girl, which he then sucked the life out of. Other day he came with his friend (she wanted to kill him) When his likeness was discovered, because his friend was hunting this monster. It came to a fight and the monster hurt the MC with one big blow to the chest, but he recovered and killed the monster with about a fire attack (like super saiyan) and then it was discovered that his father who trained him belonged to the same organization as the friend he then left. I remember that he joined that organization to make more money when he find out how much they earn.

It's probably an old manhua, I think like 3 years maybe more, and that guy was smoking in the first chapter.